# man page of swapon doesn't match with what I am seeing

Tags: partitioning, swap

I am playing around with swap and added my own swap partition. but when I do I noticed something odd.

```
test@ubuntu:~/5Gdisk$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename   Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5  partition       4192252 0       -1
/dev/sdb2  partition       5242876 0       -2
```

and my /etc/fstab

```
UUID=<bla bla> none  swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb2      swap  swap sw 0 0
```

sdb2 is the swap partition that I added.
I also checked the man page of swapon, and it says for priority it should be from -1 to 32767. So why does my swap parition has a priority of -2?

This is ubuntu 15.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man swapon` it reads:

```
   -p, --priority priority
          Specify the priority of the swap device.  priority  is  a  value
          between  0  and  32767. Higher numbers indicate higher priority.
          See swapon(2) for a full description  of  swap  priorities.  Add
          pri=value  to the option field of /etc/fstab for use with swapon
          -a.
```

so, that means in your `/etc/fstab` you would have your lines read as follows:

```
UUID=<bla bla> none  swap sw,pri=20 0 0
/dev/sdb2      none  swap sw,pri=10 0 0
```

I just used the priorities of `20` for the first one since it reads that the `"Higher numbers indicate higher priority"` in the `manpage`, then `10` for the lower priority.  Options in the `/etc/fstab` file are separated by commas `,`.

Technically, `-1` is higher than `-2` so you are probably OK.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it definitly helps, but my issue is that my man page says the values should be from -1 to 32xxx, no where does it say there should be a -2. And I noticed our two man pages aren't actually the same. So I guess there is a bit of version/distro difference and the main point is bigger number higher priority.

Comment: @D.Zou Yeah, you are right, there is a version/distro difference, but the overall swap priority should remain the same.  =)